# How to store DateTime of .net in sql server 2008 R2

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am new to .net and sql. I am trying to store the DateTime into database but i am getting exception as  "Incorrect syntax near '11' " at 11:21:57 AM i run my code so, i am getting error at time. This is my code for storing into database.
Below method will return a query.

```
    public string InsertADData(string strdateLogin, string strdateLogout, string strName, string strUsername)
    {
        DateTime dateLogin = Convert.ToDateTime(strdateLogin);
        DateTime dateLogout = Convert.ToDateTime(strdateLogout);
        return string.Format(@"INSERT INTO ADTimeData (LoginDate, LogoutDate,name,username) 
                               VALUES ({0},{1},'{2}','{3}')", dateLogin,
                                                            dateLogout,
                                                            strName.Replace("'", "''"),
                                                           strUsername.Replace("'", "''"));
    }
```

This method is for insert the records into database. Here CheckDBConnection() will open sql connection.

```
       public void InsertRecords(String strQuery)
        {
            CheckDBConnection();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = _con;
                cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

When i debug the code which i have written i am getting query i.e sqlQuery value Like this

```
      INSERT INTO ADTimeData (LoginDate, LogoutDate,name,username) 
                              VALUES (1/4/2013 11:21:57 AM,1/4/2013 11:21:57 AM,'raivnder','ravinder.g@gmail.com')
```

But i am getting exception at

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The exception is shown in  below image.
[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Personally, I would not bother thinking about the right syntax but simply use [`SqlParameter`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 2):

**In short:** The issue is in datetime format that you are passing in insert statement.

It should be done through a parametrized query. Something similare to the following sample query:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO <table> (<column>) VALUES (@value)", connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", dateTimeVariable);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Yes, i was in the middle to revise my answer.

Comment: @marc_s, you have already wrote the sql command statement, thus i will not to re-invent the same wheel here :)

Answer (score 2):

By all means - **use parametrized queries** to avoid SQL injection attacks (and to speed up performance, too!):

```
public string InsertADData(string strdateLogin, string strdateLogout, string strName, string strUsername)
{
    DateTime dateLogin = Convert.ToDateTime(strdateLogin);
    DateTime dateLogout = Convert.ToDateTime(strdateLogout);

    string query = @"INSERT INTO ADTimeData (LoginDate, LogoutDate,name,username) 
                     VALUES (@LoginDate, @LogoutDate, @name, @username)";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(.....))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LoginDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateLogin;           
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LogoutDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateLogout;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = name;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = username;

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteQuery();
        conn.Close(); 
    }
```

Never concatenate together your SQL statement with the values! This is a really really horribly bad practice - stop doing that. You should **always** use parametrized queries - no exception

Comment: Thanks for your response @marc_s. I tried your code but i am getting an exception as         "implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query."

Comment: @RavinderGangadher: is one of your columns of type `varbinary` ??

Answer (score -1):

```
public string InsertADData(string strdateLogin, string strdateLogout, string strName, string strUsername)
{
    DateTime dateLogin = Convert.ToDateTime(strdateLogin);
    DateTime dateLogout = Convert.ToDateTime(strdateLogout);
    return string.Format(@"INSERT INTO ADTimeData (LoginDate, LogoutDate,name,username) 
                           VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}')", dateLogin,
                                                        dateLogout,
                                                        strName.Replace("'", "''"),
                                                       strUsername.Replace("'", "''"));
}
```